# Check if percent field is entered (not blank) using validations rules

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to validate whether or not a user entered a value in a Percent field. This may be impossible to do using validation rules and available formulas:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZvAvAAK

Here's my code:

```
isblank(My_Special_Little_Percent_Field__c)
```

Using a validation rule, how can I validate if a user can entered a value into a percent field?

Comment: `ISBLANK(..)` doesn't work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Follow the Idea link I posted. Others have this problem as well.

Comment: really? I just tried this in dev edition and it works fine `ISBLANK(PercentField__c)` on a standard edit page and get error displayed under box. Do you have a default value specified on the percent field definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isblank(my_percent_field__c) does in fact throw an error on a field of data type percent.  I tested in my org and it seemed to be working fine - Not sure why it's not working for you.

Your other option is to set a default value and check to see if that value has changed.  For example:

if(my_percent_field__c == 0, true, false)

Comment: How strange! I opened a case with Salesforce and they verified that `isblank` will not work with Percent type fields. But when I tried this again today, it worked! I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question in 2021: Use the 'Blank Field Handling' section below the Formula field. Here you can turn on the setting 'Treat blank fields as blank' which should enable you to use 'ISBLANK()'.

[image: Blank Field Handling section]